# Is it bizarre that a professor asks every student for a 3 inch by 5 inch photograph?

Tags: etiquette, professorship, legal-issues

The professor asks this of every student. It's 2 points on an introductory assignment worth 10. Does anyone think this is bizarre? I'm against it to the point that I think it should not be allowed by the university.

**addendum**
It's an online class, by the way. A Senior Communications class is required that most have taken by now. Within that communications class it is required to upload a photo of yourself to the online university system which all classes can see, like in class rosters and private messaging. The professor also asked us to call him (it's explicitly advised at my university not to give your professor your phone number). What really annoyed me was when he then asked permission to share our email among the class. The class already has a messaging system and it can be tied into the university email. This instructor was too pathetic for me, so I dropped the course within a few days.

**addendum 2**
USA school. top 50 USNews. After seeing these comments I actually find them helpful, because the only reasons I see are to learn the students name, but in this case the professor already has photos of a strong majority of the students. What I'm getting at is the professor is really showing some incompetence and its annoying to a significant extent.

Comment: It's not common, but it's not bizarre.  Dr. [redacted] lined us up and took pictures of me and every other student in his excruciating course on compression algorithms.  By mid-term, he could match names to faces.  In many schools, the learning management system now presents pictures taken for student IDs to the instructor.

Comment: 2 points out of how many? What percentage of the final grade does the introductory assignment get weighted as?

Comment: I don't think this question gives enough information for us to answer.  Discuss this directly with the professor.

Comment: Provided it's a mugshot, where's the problem? First person to ask about it, surely, is the prof. himself. Were it *herself* would that make a difference?

Comment: It's bizarre indeed. I could imagine that with much younger pupils (though it would pose much problems) to be differently addressed and called up by a teacher with legions of pupils. Anyway s/he is 99.99% innocent, that is not my point.

Comment: My college actually provides all faculty members with photo rosters of their classes to aid, I suppose, in their learning their students names. I personally wouldn’t make my own photo roster by asking students for photographs, but don’t think that it’s exceptionally strange to do so.

Comment: A *paper* photo? Who ever prints them anymore? Millennial students probably think they are something from last century.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Your point may be valid, but you might need to review your terminology. https://xkcd.com/2165/

Comment: The situation could be made radically more bizarre by replacing the word "photograph" with "doll". (Sorry, couldn't resist.)

Comment: There is no way to answer this question without information about the context: what the stated purpose of the photo is. It's pointless to make us guess. Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: State your country, please. There might be certain privacy laws.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper "Every time I procrastinate doing my homework for that class, I feel a burning sensation under my feet or a sharp pain like somebody stuck a needle in a part of my body!"

Comment: @Thomas What would be the problem? I'm curious, since the professor obviously knows the names of who is in their class and what they look like.

Comment: @AzorAhai I don’t know if there’d be a problem, but there’s a difference between “the professor can see students while they’re in their class,” “the professor has the ability to view photos of their students in university databases while the students are in the professor’s class,” and “the professor has their own collection of student photographs that they control.”

Comment: @cpast But what would be the crime? I'm just wondering what privacy laws would prevent this

Comment: purpose of the photo is 2 points on an intro assignment worth 10. what the professor does with the photo is up to his judgment. hopefully it doesnt involve a bottle of lotion. "...it puts the lotion on the skin..." seriously seeing it.

Comment: cyber stalking is a crime. it can include repeatedly annoying someone. intimidation can be shown by such blatant abuse of power.

Comment: @Anon2019 Whether cyber stalking is a crime, depends on the country. As others have said, if you don't specify the country where this is happening, the question may be virtually impossible to answer properly and may be closed.

Comment: It did happen at my university, where we found out that all photos of male students were dumped immediately, followed by all photos of female students who were deemed not attractive enough. Of course that wouldn't happen today anymore. They would keep some goodlooking male students as well.

Comment: I remember fairly quickly the names of the famous and the infamous...

Comment: My father was a teaching lecturer at a UK university and had on his office wall (or a common staff space wall) a photo roster of the present 4 undergraduate years and the post-graduate masters years students.  Some of these behaviours are from long before the prevelance of digital photos and are the founding idea of "The Facebook" as a digital equivalent.  Could the OP clarify if they are being asked for a physical glossy photo and a digital image as the addendum makes this unclear?

Answer (score 47):

I would be interested to know why the professor wants these. I can suggest a completely innocent reason, even a reasonable one. But, I realize there are other possible interpretations. I wonder if you are brave enough to go and ask why.

But the innocent reason might be that the prof just needs a crutch to try to learn to match the names and faces of students to make interactions easier. A typical student only has a few professors so it is easy to remember names. But a professor might have tens or even hundreds of students. Some will try to remember the names and a picture can help.

To extend this, a professor might be thinking long term about students and might actually keep a file on each student, with notes about their accomplishments so that if the student asks for a LoR in the future there is something on record other than grades on which to base it. A picture in such a file could be a helpful reminder of who the student is, making such things easier.

I used to keep an index card for each of my students. No picture, though. But it served as a place to keep notes about that individual's needs and what I might need to do to serve them well. It also helped me keep track of who was asking and answering questions in class and who was more passive. Then, I could try to bring the passive ones more into the discussions.

Some professors, who teach large classes, assign specific seats to students and have a sheet of the names of the students, with pictures, in the same arrangement as the seats. Then if a hand goes up, the prof can address the student by name.

There are lots of possible positive reasons along with the ones you might be worried about. But you might want to ask. You could also, possibly, ask students who previously took classes from the prof. Or, you could go to the department office and express discomfort. You might learn the actual reason, and it might make the practice seem OK, or not.

The 2 points is immaterial (unless the max is 5). It is just a nudge. A bribe, perhaps.

Comment: In addition to the innocent reason you mention: At my institution, we require students to bring ID to every exam; it's possible the professor would rather know students by name than rely on IDs (which a truly desperate student could surely fake).

Comment: My wife used to teach intro calculus -- 4 sections of 100 students each. She asked every student to bring a picture glued to a note card with a little blurb about the student, for a minimal credit. She then learned all 400 names within the next couple of weeks. It seems like a reasonable request to be a better teacher!

Comment: In some universities a list of names and photos of the students in a class is even provided to the instructor by the administration, exactly to help the professor learn the names...

Comment: Honestly, as an adult, I'd much rather sit where I please and be addressed as "Yes, you" than be told where to sit and addressed as "David".

Comment: @DavidRicherby except in practice it works out more like "how about you answer this one? no not you I mean you. No him. With the hat. Yes you. What was I saying?"

Comment: 2 points are not immaterial.

Comment: @BoatyMcboatface, yes, out of 5, but not out of 1000. Also, any sensible grading system wouldn't be so sensitive that two points has a material effect on the overall grade. So, I need to assume that this is a very small thing to the professor.

Comment: @ASimpleAlgorithm I still vastly prefer that to being told where to sit, like I'm a six-year-old.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Yes, "Mr. Richerby" is much preferred. However, as an adult student, I prefer to take such issues with humour. It is not in my power to change other people, all I should do is live in a situation that exists... and influence it in ways that discrimination and tact allow.

Comment: I collected pictures this term as part of an optional pre-semester get-to-know-you survey and it made a big difference in how quickly I learned the names.  I used to use the ID photo roster exclusively, but many international (I am in the US) students have ID photos that look like passport photos: no glasses or earrings, neutral expression, hair pulled back behind the ears.  They look much different in their normal setting.  Plus, my students have carried a portable camera (in their phone) since they were less than 10 years old.  They are used to being photographed.

Answer (score 18):

My mother, who is a teacher, does this. She uses it to build a document with the name and face of each of her students.

When you teach several large classes, it's virtually impossible to make the link between the student you see in the classroom and the names in the listings (unless you have a very good memory and are deeply dedicated to remember more than a hundred new names a year).

This document is archived for a few years, as long as she needs an archive of the reports she graded for a class, and then destroyed.

It is called a *trombinoscope* in French and is fairly common.

Comment: I don't really think you can do this in the EU without a lot of GDPR red tape. She is just lucky nobody complained yet.

Comment: @Federico GDPR only regulates digital data stored or manipulated on computers (or more generally, what they call "automated means"). If anyone complains about good old paper+pen+glue files in the name of GDPR, the lawyers are going to laugh.

Comment: @dim: *GDPR only regulates digital data stored or manipulated on computers* ←  what you are saying is completely incorrect. The medium does not matter. See https://www.cnil.fr/fr/rgpd-de-quoi-parle-t-on (the authoritative body on GDRP in France) → they specifically mention that paper documents are in scope (*les fichiers papier sont également concernés et doivent être protégés dans les mêmes conditions*)

Comment: @WoJ in this specific case, where is the *automated* mean, though?

Comment: @dim: See Article 2, point 1 of the GDPR. For the French version (emphasis mine) *Le présent règlement s'applique au traitement de données à caractère personnel, automatisé en tout ou en partie, **ainsi qu'au traitement non automatisé de données à caractère personnel contenues ou appelées à figurer dans un fichier**.* → it does not have to be automated.

Comment: @dim: BTW, Article 4 point 2 restates that it does not have to be automated: "*«traitement», toute opération ou tout ensemble d'opérations **effectuées ou non à l'aide de procédés automatisés** (...)*

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Why wouldn't a private archive that is destroyed when no longer needed be GPRD compliant? My understanding of the law is that storing PII is fine as long as it is for an acceptable reason (and learning the students' name certainly qualifies!).

Comment: @DenisNardin It is OK, but you need to ask for explicit consent and keep it on record, give an option to opt out if the data processing is not necessary to perform your service, and provide the students with a note that details by whom, how and when their data will be used. And it's not "private use", it's within the activities of a university.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni And if you lose two points by not consenting then the consent isn't voluntary and doesn't count.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni of course, someone would have to sue the university to enforce their rights first. Just because there's a law doesn't mean it's followed religiously.

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple issues here.

1. It might not be allowed by privacy laws, or at least require explicit student consent.  Personally I think it’s ok for the instructor to ask but not right to make this mandatory.
2. I strongly feel that it’s wrong to have part of your course evaluation (however small) tied to this; I fail to see the link between the academic performance in a course and submitting a picture.

Where I work students agree when the register in a course to give access to their student ID picture to the instructor of the course.  I’m pretty sure there is an opt out feature but I could be wrong.

I usually use the picture roster to help me recognize students who send me emails or to whom I would like to speak at the start or the end of a class.

Comment: I agree, there's no academic value in submitting a photo—it seems almost unethical to require it.  I know some faculty who ask students to take a selfie outside their office door to prove they know how to get there.  They say more students come to office hours for help that way.

Answer (score 6):

There are several reasons photographs might be helpful to a professor:

1. **To try to learn your names.** This is a nice gesture, and you should be thankful that your professor is going to the effort
2. **To prevent cheating.** The professor can check the photographs of students match the person submitting the exam. This may not be obvious; the professor may recognize many students, but can double-check a few less familiar faces immediately after the exam is turned in.
3. **To track student interactions**. This actually seems like the most likely reason to me. While learning names a nice gesture, grading class participation, noting who is absent, and identifying problematic behaviors is crucial. The professor doesn't need to memorize your name for this, but does need to be able to go look up the name associated with a face under various circumstances.

**You shouldn't feel uncomfortable with this**; the professor already sees you regularly and many schools already provide student ID photographs with the roster. If anything, the fact that your professor doesn't already have your photograph is unusual.

Answer (score 2):

**I agree with you.**

He should not be allowed to force students to submit their picture. It should be voluntary. Where I live it would legally not be possible to demand this.

**BUT**

I certainly understand why he would be asking for these pictures. We had a teacher ask if anyone was fine with him photographing the class, so he could learn everyone's name and seating. Everyone agreed to the photograph(s).

Answer (score 2):

What this professor does would be illegal under EU GDPR regulations, but of course you did not specify if your University is in EU. It violates EU privacy regulation in so many ways that is impossible to describe, so I will point out just the most obvious:

1. Proportionality criteria. He/she does not need your pictures to enforce rules. He/she is fully entitled to ask any of the students for valid trustworthy personal ID when you sit the exam or join the lab (anything that involves grading) and refuse your participation if you don't provide one.
2. Securing the private data. Your image is very personal information. If the images are seen by default by other students (this implies, since this is electronic system, that they can be downloaded), this is serious breach. Additionally, to build even a database of such info, you need to have valid reason (see 1: you don't), and you need to secure it properly. Extremely high burden.

So in EU, if you report him/her to information commisioner (each country has his own) he/she will be found in violation of GDPR and University can incur heavy fine.

Now, my opinion is that the reason why he/she does this may be totally innocuous. Like the professor has prosopagnosia (difficulty in recognizing faces) and tries to remember the students faces this way. But I think it that behaviour is highly unusual and perhaps creepy (I am a man, and still creeps me out).

I do have big problems with recognizing students (and I don't have that many) but I simply require them to show me the ID card when I am unsure whether something fishy is going on. I always ask them to show their ID before I finalize their grade. Problem solved.